# plugin [id: 'dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader', version: '1.0.0']

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, mobile-development

I am trying to create any new project with the flutter. but I face this problem when running, and I do not know what is the main cause,I went to line 25 and tried to search everywhere and did not find the solution.
[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88FIw.png)

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to update Flutter and then create a new Flutter project in a different folder. After 'flutter pub get' etc., try to create a build apk from the menu. If this works properly, move your original project's Android folder to a safe location and copy the entire Android folder from the new project to the main folder of your original project. Lastly, replace the new *.iml file in the Android folder with the old one from your original project. Then try to create an APK.